# incompatible types: void cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist, types, void, incompatibility

I'm new to Java and certain that this is a simple fix that I just don't know how to do. This part of the program is meant to take a text file, turn it into an ArrayList and then return it but I get an error when returning it.

```
   package albumdatabase;

   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class Duration {   

    public static void getLength(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> listOfAlbums;
        listOfAlbums = getList();
        String arrayOfAlbums[] = new String[listOfAlbums.size()];
        arrayOfAlbums = listOfAlbums.toArray(arrayOfAlbums);
        System.out.println(arrayOfAlbums);

        for( int i = 0; i < arrayOfAlbums.length - 1; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }


    public static void getList()throws Exception{
        ArrayList<String> listOfAlbums;
        listOfAlbums = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileReader albums = new FileReader("albums.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(albums);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            listOfAlbums.add(scanner.nextLine());

        }
        System.out.println(listOfAlbums);
        scanner.close();
        return listOfAlbums;

    }
}
```

Comment: Change your method declaration to `public static ArrayList<String> getList()`

Answer (score 0):

Your getList() method return type is void and if you want to be able to assign the result of that method to an ArrayList`<T>` it will have to return ArrayList`<T>`, in your case it needs to return ArrayList`<`String`>`, so the header of your getList() should be as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getList();
```

Comment: Put them in backticks: `<>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans.

Comment: @AndyTurner Can you edit my post, so I can check the source :D, just put <String> after last ArrayList.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to write.

Comment: @AndyTurner Read above :D

Comment: I don't know what you want to change in the above.

Comment: @AndyTurner Just change last ArrayList word to ArrayList<String>

Comment: Try it yourself.

Comment: Well that was hard.